# Dungeon Defenders has choppy video and it crashes

Tags: games, fglrx

I've bought the Humble Indie Bundle 7 and I want to play Dungeon Defenders but all I get is choppy video, freezing and, later on, unclickable and window.

I use AMD graphic with fglrx and Intel i5.

Has anyone managed to make it work?

I've managed to play first level but it is still far from playable. I've left that small window mode and it somehow worked, but I couldn't get mouse outside to unity and resolution was bad.

Comment: Do you have the valve repos installed?  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Valve

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).